# BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG not working fine

Tags: buildroot

I am following steps 4 & 5 in this link :--
https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_quick_guide_to_storing_your_project_specific_customizations

I am running following command :---
make busybox-update-config BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG=/home/dinesh/busybox/busybox.config

But busybox .config file doesn't go to right path set "/home/dinesh/busybox/busybox.config".

[image: Terminal Output]

Comment: Anyone who can suggest .. have i invoked make command correctly ?

Comment: First, if you have set variable in most shells you should use pattern like this `VAR=value mycommand`. Second, this variable can't be set through command line. I think you should try to modify `.config` file and set `BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG` to correct value there.